# Cordova dialogs plugin not working after using the camera

Tags: ios, cordova, camera, dialog

While testing my app I have just realised that the Dialogs plugin stops working after a return from taking a photo (using the camera plugin).

It works perfectly fine before this and if I restart the application it works how it should.

Has anyone else run into this problem and found a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you have some javascript error, launch the app, open desktop safari and inspect the app to see any console error

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I've just discovered the same problem.

Comment: @JamieCarruthers I don't think I did unfortunately, haven't done Cordova in a long time, focusing on Native apps now, sorry!

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue via XCode. The native Dialog was trying to be displayed before the Camera/Gallery modal had completely disappeared, which isn't allowed. I wrapped the dialog call in a 500ms timeout to ensure the Camera/Gallery modal was completely removed first.